# Python RandomForestClassifer - Unknown label type: 'continuous' error

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to expand my programming skills and thought I would try machine learning. So this is for learning and not for anything serious. With that said, I am retrieving some information from a sqlite database, then trying to run it through a RandomForestClassifier but I get an error.

> line 172, in check_classification_targets
>      raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
>   ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'"

my code is as follows:

```
series= cur.fetchall()
y = [x[1] for x in series]
x = [x[2] for x in series]
y = array(y).astype(float)
x = array(x).astype(int)
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier()
rf_model.fit(x, y)
```

My arrays are of the shape:
    y.shape
    (50,)
    x.shape
    (50,)

What am I missing? Searching SO it seems like it needs the y variable in a string format but I still get the error:

> "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
>   ValueError: Number of labels=50 does not match number of samples=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I needed to transform the array with `X = X[:, None]`